# Bluetooth headset records nothing but consistent noise

Tags: audio, bluetooth, skype

I have this RZE-BT180H Bluetooth (BT) headset from Toshiba and I want to skype handsfree using the BT connection. I can hear with this headset but the problem is that it does not record anything but buzzing, as I managed to capture it using the Windows Sound tool (R) and Streamosaur (L) and thus you can see the high stereo levels caused by this buzz.

[image]

The headset skypes nicely with my phone; I wish it to do the same in Windows.

Here are some specs:

- Windows 10 x64 Pro
- Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth module (VID 13D3 & PID 3304)
- Toshiba RZE-BT180H Bluetooth headset

Since the headset offers these BT services: (i) Audio Sink; (ii) Hands-free Telephony; and (iii) Remote Control, I tried disabling (i) and/or (ii) but that did not stop recording the buzz. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause**

If you are using the driver that Windows installed automatically, then you'll have to switch to the driver that came with your laptop, including the software package that came along since it contains some other protocols that run all of the components in the device and are capable of filtering the signals, which might be the cause of that noise.

**Solution**

Use the drivers for the Bluetooth module from your PC maker. If the driver was not made available to newer Windows editions, you can set the compatibility mode to your PC's original OS edition (but don't use different OS architecture). If you find only the driver for Windows 7 x64 and you are on Windows 10 x64, download it and install it under Windows 7 compatibility mode.

**Note**

Old BT devices may not run smoothly in newer Windows editions and using legacy drivers could cause errors requesting reboots. This is why relying on Windows to set up the drivers is somehow convenient; it will use the minimum software that is digitally signed and runs the device for most users and will save memory, disc space, and startup time. If you rarely skype on PC, you better use the classic way and plug the headset's cable.